# BI Engine on GCP

Tags: python, google-bi-engine

I am not able to find any way to use BI Engine outside Looker. Is there an API for BI Engine on top of Big Query so that it can be used with Python or any other language client?

Answer (score 1):

Relevant Update: We have preview for BigQuery BI Engine through SQL interface. I makes your use-case really easy - keep using the same BigQuery API. Once BI Engine reservation is configured, queries will get acceleration without any changes on the client.

Once you create reservation, queries that come through regular BigQuery API for corresponding project will get acceleration.

See details:
https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/sql-interface-overview

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not yet.  It’s currently limited to Data Studio

https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/introduction#limitations

Although check out materialized views for a performance optimization.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro